# Not able to get Amazon SNS logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudtrail

Below is the log stream I am getting with the CLI command :

[image]

And I am also getting the log streams as below:

[image]

But while accessing a log stream I am getting the below error:

[image]

So could you please help me where I am wrong or why the error is coming. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the values for log stream name and group name as double quoted strings, may be the params are not getting passed correctly

Comment: Try `aws logs get-log-events --log-group-name "<group_name_in_quotes>" --log-stream-name "<again name in quotes>"`